# getCountry method error

Tags: java, arrays

Can someone offer some insight on why the code doesnt work? the problem lies in the part countries `[numCountries]=newCountry;`

I'm not sure why it keeps saying type mismatch cannot convert `Country[]` to Country, but I thought my `countries[numCountries]` is `Country[]` type since I already called it at the 2nd line of code as that type?

```
public class World{

private Country[] countries;
private int numCountries=0;

public boolean addCountry(Country[] newCountry){
    if(!(newCountry==null)){
        countries[numCountries]=newCountry;     //the newcountry part doesnt work, red zigzag line underlining it here im not sure why
        numCountries++;
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;

       }


}
```

Comment: +1 for telling us the error message and where you think the problem is. :)

Comment: Because you have newCountry declared as an array, not a single Country.

Comment: thanks to jmort and dave but well @DaveNewton that doesnt matter cus as long as it doesnt = null the whole thing will work, its just a precaution for if someone decides to be stupid and make it null when they try to add a new country haha

Comment: what Dave is saying is it's neater to write `if(newCountry!=null){`

Comment: My point was that (!(newCountry == null)) is harder to read than (newCountry != null). Which is harder to read than reversing the logic and returning immediately if (newCountry == null).

Comment: ah! understood thanks! sorry about it haha

Comment: This is a totally different question now and the answer is now nonsensical. The issue is you never instantiated the country array, only a reference to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You method says that you're adding ***a*** Country, not adding an array of Country, so your method parameter should probably lose the array brackets `[]`.  This way the method makes much more sense, since it passes in what you say should be passed in -- a single Country object. You'll also want to check in your method that you're not exceeding the size of the countries array before attempting to add another Country to the array. This can be done with a simple if statement.

If you want to add an array of Country, then you may wish to create another method, say `addCountries(Country[] newCountries)`. But I don't think that you really want to do this, so stick with the corrected current method.

If any of this doesn't make sense, please ask -- just write a comment below this answer.

Comment: thanks that made sense, but now it compiles but i got a null pointer error which is quite weird since i have already created new world new country and new cities already, i have also editted my code and question at the top ^^

Comment: @user1343502: you might want to ask a new question for this. But if you do or don't you will need to indicate *which* line is throwing the NPE (NullPointerException), as that will hold the key to seeing what variable is null and why.

Comment: @user1343502: See Dave's latest comment which tells you why you're getting your NPE.

Answer (score 3):

The square brackets after Country mean that you're addCountry method is adding an array of countries, but you most likely want to add only one country at a time.

So, change it to:

```
public boolean addCountry(Country newCountry){
    ....
}
```